# How can I stop isNaN from returning an error for a blank field?

Tags: javascript, forms

EDIT:

Ok so I'm updating this question, to show what I've built as I've still not been able to fix this issue. Here is an image of what I've got. So as you can see,

[image]

When the user enters a value, the calculation (they are just percentage and total calculations are done "onkeyup". As you can see because of this they return "NaN". Is there a way for me to stop the field displaying a NaN and then subsequently only showing the total values?

I have thought about this and I could just get all the fields to calculate as soon as something is input into the final field? What do you think. Apologies to all those that had perviously answered my question, I am still trying to figure out the best approach, I'm just not as good with JavaScript as I am with HTML/CSS!!

Comment: What are `sInput`, `dInput`, and `pInput`?  Show how you assign values to those variables.

Comment: Why not just read the input into a variable and if it's null set it to zero?

Comment: Sorry, those inputs are user entered inputs, that are taken from a form. I'll edit the post to include them.

Comment: You could fairly easily distinguish between blank entries and non-blank invalid entries for the purposes of your error checking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try writing a checkNumber function that takes the entered value as its argument (rather than referring directly to each field inside the function). Something like this:

```
var checkNumber = function (testval) {
  if ( isNaN(testval) ) {
    alert('Bad!');
    // clean up field? highlight in red? etc.
  } else {
    // call your calculation function
  }
}
```

Then bind that function to the `keyup` event of each form field. There are a number of ways to do this. Look into [`addEventListener()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.addEventListener), or the binding features of a framework like jQuery ([`.delegate()`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) or [`.keyup()`](http://api.jquery.com/keyup/), e.g.).

Note that if you do bind the function to the event, you won't have to explicitly pass in the value argument. You should be able to work with a field's value within the function via `this.value`. So you'd have something like this:

```
var checkNumber = function () {
  if ( isNaN( this.value ) ) {
    alert('Bad!');
    // clean up field? highlight in red? etc.
  } else {
    // call your calculation function
  }
}
```

And then (with a naive binding approach by ID):

```
document.getElementById('id_of_a_field').addEventListener('keyup', checkNumber, true);
```

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just initialize the text box with a default value, say 0?

Comment: I did try this but I need the field to be blank (it's a requirement). I did set the text box value defaults to '0' but got told they needed to begin blank!

Answer (score 0):

How about use [short-circuit evaluation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators#Short-Circuit_Evaluation) with [**jsFiddle example**](http://jsfiddle.net/quYSD/1/)

**EDIT for parseFloat:**

```
function checkNumber() 
{
    var sInput = parseFloat(document.getElementById('sInput').value || 0);
    var dInput = parseFloat(document.getElementById('dInput').value || 0);
    var pInput = parseFloat(document.getElementById('pInput').value || 0);
    if (isNaN(sInput) || isNaN(dInput) || isNaN(pInput)) {
        alert("You entered an invalid character. Please press 'Reset' and enter a number.");
    }
}
```

So if pInput is undefined just use 0, but if the input has value then use that value.

SIDE NOTE: white space is actually a number, `+'            '; // 0`

Comment: Thanks! I'm still playing around with this trying to get it to work, but thanks for your help.

Comment: `isNaN(x || 0)` is never true for any value of `x` so this just turns the alert off.  If `isNaN(x)` is true, then `x` is falsey, so `0` is passed to `isNaN` instead and `isNaN(0)` is `false`.

Comment: @Mike, you are wrong, `isNaN("aa" || 0) // true` and here is the working demo I made: http://jsfiddle.net/quYSD/

Comment: @Joey, ah.  Good point.  Is there an `x` such that `"number" === typeof x && isNaN(x || 0)`?  I ask because `sInput` and friends are all the result of `parseFloat`.

Comment: @Joey, Not your fault.  I made an overly general assertion.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use 3 different functions or an argument to identify which of the inputs the user is pressing? If each of the inputs calls checkNumber(1), checkNumber(2) and checkNumber(3) you can only validate the input that the user is using instead of validating all 3 at the same time.

Alternatively you can use input validation and instead of an alert just return false to prevent the user from inputing invalid chars

Comment: true, I could do this, but I want to keep it within one function. I'm checking all options at the moment and will see which is the best choice!

Comment: Like i said, you can also use 1 function with an argument